# Filter run only once, how make it run every request

Tags: java, authentication, servlet-filters

in my website i have a folder 
../private/* 
containing 2 pages where i want them to be acessed only by logged in users.

if i open those 2 pages hundred times, i'm correctly redirected to the login page.
once i'm logged in and i open the pages, the filter is called just once per page, the second time i open the page, the filter it's not called anymore.

that's the code:

```
@WebFilter("/private/*")
public class FilterLoginPages implements Filter {


@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;       
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);    

    System.out.println("IN THE FILTER");

    /* logic of session control */
    /* some code, some code */


    if(expiringDate != null && expiryDate.after(dateNow)){
        System.out.println("user logged in correctly ..");          
        //open the page
        request.getRequestDispatcher(((HttpServletRequest) request).getServletPath()).forward(request, response);

    }else{
        System.out.println("user not logged in ..");
        //No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.html"); 
    }       
}
```

the output is "IN THE FILTER" always when i'm not logged in and i try to open the pages, once i'm logged in i get "IN THE FILTER" once, then nothing for the next openings.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually sending a request to the server, and not just reloading the page from the browser cache? Also, you shouldn't forward in order to serve the page. You should just call `chain.doFilter(req, res)`.

Comment: Probably there is another filter before this filter that does redirect or forward instead of  `chain.doFilter`?

Comment: The code in the webpage is only html, no links to servlets.
I thought that the filter must handle every call to the page.. 
And no, actually i'm not that sure the browser load the page from the cache, is there a way to verify it?
I also tried with     chain.doFilter    but i've got the same issue. Thanks.